# Cat6 cable not working with Asus RT-AC68U

Tags: networking

In my home network I have 3 Cat6 FTP cables leading to different rooms. When I connect them to a router/modem provided by my internet provider (Technicolor TC7200) they all work fine, but that router lacks some features.

I want to use my Asus RT-AC68U, which would connect all my wired and wireless devices and route the traffic to TC7200. Problem is, that ONE of the cables does not seem to work when I connect it to the Asus router. Any device that I try to connect to that cable just reports "cable unplugged". I've tried another switch and the cable works fine, it only refuses to cooperate with the Asus router. It makes no difference to which of the four ports on the Asus I connect it, the LED indicating cable link for that port does not light up.

Anybody has an idea what could be causing this?